# Presenting multiple sql tables

Tags: c#, winforms, t-sql, linq-to-sql

Sorry if this question have been asked before but I can't find what I'm looking for anywhere.

**Setup:** I have a MS SQL database with 3 tables

**Table** - FoodInfo
**Column** - FoodId(PK), DanName

**Table** - CompName
**Column** - CmpId(PK), CmpName

**Table** - Nutrients(junction table)
**Column** - FoodId(FK), CmpId(fk), BestLoc

For every DanName row there is associated about 8 CmpName and for every CmpName there is associated 1 BestLoc

That leads to DanName getting repeated 8 times when I show the data in my winform.

The problem is, I want to present DanName in one line with the associated CmpName's and their values.

Something like:
DanName - CmpName1 - BestLoc value - CmpName2 - BestLoc value - CmpName3 - BestLoc value.. and so on.

I am very flexible about the solution, but I'm not sure what path to follow.
should I try to create a table in the DB which look as I want it to and put it in a DataGridView, or should I try to solve it with Linq-To-SQL and put it in a listview?

As said, I'm pretty flexible about the solution, I just don't want the data in at textbox.
I would also like it to be possible to use the data I retrieve and use it elsewhere in my program.

If anyone have a solution I would love to see an example of it.

**Edit:**
To be a little more detailed, and with some code samples.

My DAL class with linq

```
void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Table<FoodInfo> FoodInfo = db.GetTable<FoodInfo>();
    Table<CompName> CompName = db.GetTable<CompName>();
    Table<Nutrient> Nutrients = db.GetTable<Nutrient>();

    var foods =
        from compname in CompName
        join nutrients in Nutrients on compname.CompId equals nutrients.CompId
        join foodinfo in FoodInfo on nutrients.FoodId equals foodinfo.FoodId
        where foodinfo.DanName.StartsWith(searchWord) && (compname.CompId >= 0
                                                      && compname.CompId < 8)
        select new { foodinfo.DanName, compname.CmpNamDK, nutrients.BestLoc };

    foreach (var food in foods)
    {
        DanName = food.DanName;
        Compname = food.CmpNamDK;
        BestLoc = food.BestLoc;

        OnSearchResultArgs OSR = new OnSearchResultArgs(DanName, Compname, BestLoc);
        onResult(this, OSR);
    }
}
```

which triggers an eventhandler in my form and send over the results and execute this code:

```
listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
listView1.Columns.Add("DanName", 100);
listView1.Columns.Add("CompName", 150);
listView1.Columns.Add("BestLoc", 50);

private void UpdateControls(object sender, OnSearchResultArgs e)
{
    var item = new ListViewItem();
    item.Text = e.DanName;
    item.SubItems.Add(e.CompName);
    item.SubItems.Add(e.BestLoc);
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

The UpdateControl is getting invoked, but I don't think that is necessary to put in here.

and by this I get the following:
[image]

I want to turn those 8 rows into 1 row. like:
[image]

Comment: _I just dont want the data in a textbox_ Do you mean that all entries (DanName - CmpName1 - BestLoc - CmpName2 - BestLoc ...) should be in separate cells in the grid? Or could it be DanName in one cell and the other data concatenated in one adjacent cell?

Comment: This sounds like a presentation problem, not a data problem. Without more information about your presentation tier, it's hard to offer any advice on how to do it there since it's dependent on what you are binding to or how you are presenting it. If you really want to concatenate the data, you'll have to answer Gert's question above about clarifying your target format.

Comment: @user2203275 It looks like you want to  Pivot the data.It is Possible both in linq and t-sql. If you post some code what you have done so far then people here can help you.

Comment: Sorry for not beeing more detailed, hope det update will help.
This Pivot looks like it could do the trick. can you give an example with my code ?

Comment: Why don't you just type a sample output, these scrawly lines don't really make it clearer. It suggests that there is a level in `CompName`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update if anyone runs into the same question as i had.

First i tried the solution from @JonPayne, with the T-SQL.. it solved my problem, but worked very slow for me. Maby i was doing i wrong. i dont know.

I ended up with making a pivot method from a guide i found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22008/C-Pivot-Table

Very simple, I query my unordered data from the SQL-Server, put it in a datatable and format the datatable with the pivot method, that returns a ordered datatable.

Answer (score 0):

I have two solutions, both have their drawbacks.

The first solution is to manually pivot the data, but this isn't very dynamic as you'll have to change the query should you start having more than 8 CmpName and the second solution is to put all CmpName and BestLoc values in one column.

The T-SQL below should demonstrate both solutions.

```
--** Set up test data
DECLARE @FoodInfo Table (FoodId INT, DanName varchar(50));
DECLARE @CompName TABLE (CmpId INT, CmpName VARCHAR(50));
DECLARE @Nutrients TABLE (FoodId INT , CmpId INT, BestLoc VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO @FoodInfo (FoodId, DanName)
VALUES  (1, 'Abrikos, torret');

INSERT INTO @CompName (CmpId, CmpName)
VALUES  (1, 'Energi'),(2, 'Protein, total'),(3, 'total-N'),(4, 'Fedt, total'),(5, 'Maettede fedtsyrer'),(6, 'monoumaett, fedtsyrer'),(7, 'polyumaett, fedtsyrer'),(8, 'kulhydrat, tilgaengelig');

INSERT INTO @Nutrients(FoodId, CmpId, BestLoc)
VALUES  (1,1,1159),(1,2,2.9),(1,3,0.5),(1,4,1.7),(1,5,0.1),(1,6,0.6),(1,7,0.6),(1,8,57.2);

--** Standard query
SELECT fi.DanName
     , cn.CmpName
     , n.BestLoc
  FROM @FoodInfo AS fi
  JOIN @Nutrients AS n
    ON fi.FoodId = n.FoodId
  JOIN @CompName AS cn
    ON n.CmpId = cn.CmpId;

--** Manual Pivot
WITH sortCTE AS (
        SELECT fi.DanName
             , cn.CmpName
             , n.BestLoc
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fi.FoodId ORDER BY cn.CmpId) AS 'col'
          FROM @FoodInfo AS fi
          JOIN @Nutrients AS n
            ON fi.FoodId = n.FoodId
          JOIN @CompName AS cn
            ON n.CmpId = cn.CmpId)
SELECT s.DanName
     , MAX(CASE WHEN s.col = 1 THEN s.CmpName END) AS Cmp1
     , MAX(CASE WHEN s.col = 1 THEN s.BestLoc END) AS BestLoc1
     , MAX(CASE WHEN s.col = 2 THEN s.CmpName END) AS Cmp2
     , MAX(CASE WHEN s.col = 2 THEN s.BestLoc END) AS BestLoc2
     , MAX(CASE WHEN s.col = 3 THEN s.CmpName END) AS Cmp3
     , MAX(CASE WHEN s.col = 3 THEN s.BestLoc END) AS BestLoc3
     , MAX(CASE WHEN s.col = 4 THEN s.CmpName END) AS Cmp4
     , MAX(CASE WHEN s.col = 4 THEN s.BestLoc END) AS BestLoc4
     , MAX(CASE WHEN s.col = 5 THEN s.CmpName END) AS Cmp5
     , MAX(CASE WHEN s.col = 5 THEN s.BestLoc END) AS BestLoc5
     , MAX(CASE WHEN s.col = 6 THEN s.CmpName END) AS Cmp6
     , MAX(CASE WHEN s.col = 6 THEN s.BestLoc END) AS BestLoc6
     , MAX(CASE WHEN s.col = 7 THEN s.CmpName END) AS Cmp7
     , MAX(CASE WHEN s.col = 7 THEN s.BestLoc END) AS BestLoc7
     , MAX(CASE WHEN s.col = 8 THEN s.CmpName END) AS Cmp8
     , MAX(CASE WHEN s.col = 8 THEN s.BestLoc END) AS BestLoc8
  FROM sortCTE AS s
 GROUP BY s.DanName;

--** All in one column
SELECT fi.DanName
     , ISNULL(SUBSTRING((SELECT ', ' + cn.CmpName + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), n.BestLoc)
                           FROM @Nutrients AS n
                           JOIN @CompName AS cn
                             ON n.CmpId = cn.CmpId
                          WHERE fi.FoodId = n.FoodId
                       ORDER BY cn.CmpId ASC FOR XML PATH('') ), 3, 5000), '') AS 'Cmp'
  FROM @FoodInfo AS fi;
```

I'm sorry but I don't know what the equivalent queries would look like in LINQ but this could give you some idea what you are aiming for.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @JohnPayne.. Sorry for the late answer, iv been out off town lateley.

This looks like just the solution im looking for, right now i have created a pivot class in my C# program, but the program is really slow in the process, so i think that making the pivot in the database is det correct solution, i will try it out later this week and return with an result.. for now i will accept your answer. Thanks (: !